# Is it true about center?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group (finite ) and let $G$ be a center of $Z$, now assume that $G = G_1 \times G_2 \cdots G_k$ is the decomposition of $G$, where each $G_i$ is indecomposable.

Is it true that

$G /Z = G_1/Z \times G_2/Z \times ...G_k/Z$ ?

or just tell the correct relation here.

Answer (score 4):

It is clear that $Z(G)=Z(G_1)\times Z(G_2)\times ...\times Z(G_k)$. Consider the map $\phi : G\rightarrow G_1/Z(G_1)\times ...\times G_k/Z(G_k)$ with $\phi(g)=(\overline{g_1},...,\overline{g_k})$ where $g=(g_1,...,g_k)$. What is the kernel?

Comment: please add more detail to your answer. I am naive in this field.

Comment: Which part is problematic?